# iOS 11 How to remove black shadow when app is launched

Tags: ios, ios11

In iOS 11 when user taps on app icon it shows a black colour, in system apps it doesn't happen even i've noticed this in other apps from different developers it doesn't happen. I'm attaching a screenshot.[image]

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean. Can you provide a more self explanatory screenshot if it's hard to verbalize?

Comment: well, i'm trying to say is, when app is launched there is black coloured background, which i've pointed later it turns into launch screen. my app icon has no black no other colours.

Comment: It could be because of the UIWindow color, which is black.

Comment: Is it black or dark blue? Anyhow - is this part of your launch screen?

Comment: no neither its colour of my UIWindow because i've set my windows background colour to blue as seen as my app icon, nor its colour of my launch screen. i fact when app is launched the black colour turns in to colour of my launch screen

Comment: @VidyaMurthy as i believe UIWindow will not take effect unless app is launched. and this happens before app launched.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was cause in my app.
I think your app icon shape is not square.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/

This link says

---

### Attribute  -> value

Format   ->   PNG       
Color Space -> sRGB or P3
Layers   ->   Flattened with no transparency
Resolution ->   Varies. 
Shape ->    Square with no rounded corners

---

App Icon Shape should be square with no rounded corners.
So please try to change your app icon's shape if your app icon's shape is not square.